# MapView cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

Hi I am new to Android programming and working on Eclipse. I am having an error "MapView cannot be resolved or is not a field" in the following program:

```
   import java.util.List;

   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Canvas;
   import android.graphics.Paint;
   import android.graphics.Point;
   import android.graphics.RectF;
   import android.location.Location;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;


  import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
  import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
  import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
  import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
  import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class Map extends MapActivity {

MapView map;
long start;
long stop;
private final int mRadius = 5;

public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMapview);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.displayZoomControls(true);
    map.setSatellite(true);
    map.setStreetView(true);
    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    List<Overlay> overlaylist = map.getOverlays();
    overlaylist.add(t);

    }
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

    if (shadow == false) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();{
            if(extras!=null){
                String longitude =extras.getString("Longitude");
                String latitude =extras.getString("Latitude");
            }
        }

        double latitude;
        double longitude; 
        GeoPoint geoPoint;
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) ( latitude *1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));

        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y - mRadius, point.x + mRadius, point.y + mRadius);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(250, 255, 255, 255);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

        Paint backPaint = new Paint();
        backPaint.setARGB(175, 50, 50, 50);
        backPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        RectF backRect = new RectF(point.x + 2 + mRadius, point.y - 3*mRadius, point.x + 65, point.y + mRadius);

        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(backRect, 5, 5, backPaint);
        canvas.drawText("This is it", point.x + 2*mRadius, point.y,paint);
}
    super.draw(canvas.MapView.shadow);      
}
```

I don knw why this error pop up.
I alrdy try to fix it but the mapview error is always there

Comment: Are you running this in an emulator? Did you create it with Google APIs?

Comment: Got my google API... Emulator is running well too...

Comment: is the `draw` method your own or are you trying to override the onDraw method?

Comment: The draw method is my own. I add the draw method into the Overlay

Answer (score 6):

Choose Project > Properties from the Eclipse main menu. In the Properties window, click on Android in the list of categories on the left. Then, choose a build target that contains the Google APIs in the checklist on the right. Click OK to close the window.

Comment: Then fix `canvas.MapView.shadow` to be whatever is correct, as that syntax is probably incorrect. I suspect that you want commas where there are periods.

Comment: Ya... TQ I thk it should be commas... But now another error arise... It said that "The method draw(Canvas, MapView, boolean) is undefined for the type MapActivity"... I know the method draw is from type Overlay...

Comment: @SimonCheah: "Is there anyway to fix this?" -- you claim that you added "the draw method into the Overlay", except that there is no `Overlay` in your code. There are references to a `Touchy` that might be an `Overlay`,  but I have no idea if it is or not. Perhaps your `draw()` implementation should be in `Touchy`, instead of `Map`.

Comment: I mean if I change the (public class Map extends MapActivity) into (public class Map extends Overlay) the error is gone but others part of programming need that extends of MapActivity...

Comment: @SimonCheah: Newcomers to programming should learn Java before trying to get into Android development.