# android mapView not resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3

I have the following problem with mapView in eclipse/java.

Using `mapView.getOverlays()` I get the error.

> mapView cannot be resolved

I tried to use a local variable for mapView (using MapView) but it crashes.
Is mapView declared somewhere ?

I import `com.google.android.maps.MapView;`

but I can't access the code and [the offcial doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView) did not help

and [MapView cannot be resolved or is not a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667530/mapview-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field) did not help too

I have installed the SDK and checked Google API in Eclipse

> project build target

I can display a map without problem

and my MainActivity extends MapActivity

Here is the full code

```
package com.example.test_app;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import com.example.test_app.MyLocation;
import com.example.test_app.MyLocation.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.content.Context;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationProvider;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity

{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    if (mapView == null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mapview is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location loc){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," long : " +loc.getLongitude()+ " lat :"+ loc.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        }
    };
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}/* End of UseGps Activity */
```

Comment: Do you have Google API installed??

Comment: Have you declared MapView in your code?

Comment: try to change "extends Activity" to "extends MapActivity"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in Your menifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

in your layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="---- Your Key -------"
    />
```

You have a sily mistake. Move your setContentView above the declairation of the MapView. For that reason it gettting that error

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
```

Comment: yep , but while i am editting my answer you also found your silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is solved.

I had to use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Before `MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);`

Stupid mistake.